# How to convert multipartfile into Blob type

Tags: hibernate

Hi I am working with saving Image into DB,I am Taking Image as Multipart and trying to convert into `Blob` type.
I do this method:

```
Blob blob=Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).createBlob(multipartFile.getInputStream(),multipartFile.getSize());
```

But getting `Nullpointer Exception While Executing`.
the file is Unable to convert multipart into `Blob`, any other Method to saving Image into DB.

Answer (score 4):

```
MultipartFile savedFile;
savedFile=itemView.getImgFile();//file from model attribute 
Blob blob=Hibernate.createBlob(savedFile.getInputStream()); // hibernate method for create blob 
//Save method will be call here
```

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/
i followed above tutorial

Comment: I get this error `The method createBlob(InputStream) is undefined for the type Hibernate` when i use the `createBlob()` method, as it is deprecated and in Hibernate version 4..

Answer (score 3):

You can use this approach.
Get multipart data and convert it into byte arrray and then convert to Blob

```
for (MultipartFile file : productsBean.getData()) {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    Blob blob = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(bytes);
    }
```

It's working for me :)

Comment: This is not an efficient way as this loads whole data (byte array) into memory (RAM) from multipart object (which doesn't contain data but contains reference to data).

Answer (score 0):

`BlobProxy` can be used.

```java
import org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.BlobProxy;
// ...
Blob blob = BlobProxy.generateProxy(multipartFile.getInputStream(),
                                    multipartFile.getSize());
```